# How can I get menu data on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I use a Wordpress theme on my website, and I need to make a custom menu bar.
But I don't know How can I get the menu data and use it with PHP. I see some PHP code in my theme, but I don't understand it.

I need to generate this code:

```
<div>
    <div>Menu</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>       
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2 Child1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2 Child2</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Finally, I need to check the number of menu items and make a `<li>` tag for each menu and its children.

Comment: Why you have a `DIV` inside a `ul` between a `li`? Your menu have some markup errors.

Comment: Thank you. I fix it now.
but I'm not focus on font end. I want to know how to get menu data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sarin, are you writing a custom WP theme or working off of an existing theme? It sounds like the ladder?

Generally speaking if you want to create a menu in the WordPress that **is admin editable** and then you will need to use `wp_nav_menu($args)` in your theme file (as documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). Of course in order for the menu to appear in the WordPress admin or render as expected when calling `wp_nav_menu()` you will need to be sure to register the menu inside of your `functions.php` file using `register_nav_menus($locations)`.

If you are looking to make the menu be auto generated by your PHP code and **not be admin editable** then you likely will want to use `wp_list_pages($args)` (as documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

If you offer some additional guidance as to what you are trying to do exactly then I might be able to offer more help.

Comment: thank you so much.I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress already has a [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function that generates the HTML of a menu created in the admin. It has some configuration options allowing you to alter, to a certain extent, the generated HTML.

But if you want more control on the generated HTML, you can create a [Menu Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) and pass it to the `wp_nav_menu` (as the 'walker' option). In a few words, the Walker is a class that contains special functions that are called for each menu items and return HTML. By creating your own Menu Walker, you can control the HTML.

Finally, you may also want to have a look at the [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) function which returns the menu items of a menu as an array (each menu item is an augmented WP_Post object). Note that even if your menu has multiple levels, the array returned by `wp_get_nav_menu_items` is not multi-dimension. The hierarchy is defined by properties inside each menu item (`menu_item_parent`).

Comment: thank you so much.I will try it tomorrow.